# Data function of Parent is called twice

Tags: vue.js

I'm using VueJS 2.5.16 displaying custom component:

```
<datafieldcheckbox class="filterComponents" :filtervalue="filterAll" @call-method="callfilteredproducts"></datafieldcheckbox>
```

and in main vue app data, I'm using data function returning some data:

```
data: {
    get filterAll() {
       console.log(11111111111);
    }
}
```

this `filterAll` is called twice. Am I wrong or any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

That is because you declared and called `filterAll()` within data scope, and then you set it as prop for component, and it is called again. You should move your `filterAll()` method in methods, and remove it from prop for component.

```
data(){
    return{
        filtervalue : this.filterAll()
    }
},

methods:{
    filterAll()
    {
        console.log(11111111111);
    }
}
```